# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pymysql' on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: python, ubuntu-16.04, pymysql, python-3.7

I'm new to Python. I'm trying to connect python3 with MySql on Ubuntu 16.04. I executed following commands:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get -y install python3-pip
pip3 install PyMySQL
```

After successful installation, when I try to import PyMySql, it gives me error:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pymysql'
```

To import I used syntax:

```
import pymysql
```

PS: Python 3.7.0 and python 2.7.12 was already installed on my system.

Comment: Were you definitely in your Python 3 interpreter when you tried to do the import?

Comment: when you run it, are you using `python3 *.py`?

Comment: Yes, I'm using 'python3 filename.py' to execute my code

Comment: @surbhibam did you try `python3 -m pip install PyMySQL?`

Comment: @muzol, Yes I tried that as well.